# Show that the function $f(x,y)=(x+y)e^{xy}$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus

Show that the function $f(x,y)=(x+y)e^{xy}$ is differentiable

[image]

[image]

I've been looking at the blue circle part for 3 hours, still can't figure out why they did it like that. The definition for differentiability is:

If f is differentiable at a, then there is an n by m matrix B such that

$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-B\cdot h}{|h|} \rightarrow 0 
 \text { as}\ h\rightarrow 0$$

So what exactly happened there in the blue circle part?

Comment: honestly i wouldn’t try to get bogged down in the details of this proof. just show that the product of two differentiable functions is differentiable as a consequence of the chain rule and the fact that the map $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is differentiable.

Comment: @C Squared Actually thats how i solved this question in the beginning, this is the official solution, i did get the points for this question but they said next time do it according to the definition, ie. like in the solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that happens in the blue circle is that the expression

$$L(h_1,h_2)$$ gets "un-expanded". Notice that

$$\begin{align}
L(h_1, h_2) &= [e^{x_0y_0}(1+y_0(x_0+y_0))\quad e^{x_0y_0}(1+x_0(x_0+y_0))]\cdot (h_1, h_2) 
\\&= h_1\cdot e^{x_0y_0}(1+y_0(x_0+y_0)) + h_2\cdot e^{x_0y_0}(1+x_0(x_0+y_0))
\\&=e^{x_0y_0}(h_1 + h_1y_0(x_0+y_0) + h_2 + h_2x_0e^{x_0y_0}(x_0+y_0))
\\&=e^{x_0y_0}((h_1+h_2) + (h_1y_0 + h_2x_0)(x_0+y_0))
\\&=e^{x_0y_0}(h_1+h_2) + (x_0+y_0)e^{x_0y_0}(h_1y_0 + h_2x_0)
\end{align}$$

---

So, in the blue circle, what is happening is:

$$\begin{align}
(h_1+h_2)e^{x_0y_0} +& (h_1+h_2)e^{x_0y_0}(e^{h_2x_0+h_1y_0+h_1h_2} - 1)
\\ +& (x_0+y_0)e^{x_0y_0}(h_1y_0 + h_2x_0) 
\\+& (x_0+y_0)e^{x_0y_0} [e^{h_2x_0+h_1y_0+h_1h_2} - 1 - (x_0h_2+y_0h_1)] 
\\=e^{x_0y_0}(h_1+h_2) +& (x_0+y_0)e^{x_0y_0}(h_1y_0 + h_2x_0)  
\\ +& (h_1+h_2)e^{x_0y_0}(e^{h_2x_0+h_1y_0+h_1h_2} - 1) 
\\ +& (x_0+y_0)e^{x_0y_0} [e^{h_2x_0+h_1y_0+h_1h_2} - 1 - (x_0h_2+y_0h_1)]
\\=L(h_1,h_2)
\\ +& (h_1+h_2)e^{x_0y_0}(e^{h_2x_0+h_1y_0+h_1h_2} - 1) 
\\ +& (x_0+y_0)e^{x_0y_0} [e^{h_2x_0+h_1y_0+h_1h_2} - 1 - (x_0h_2+y_0h_1)]
\end{align}$$

Note that in the first equality, I just reordered the summands. In the second, I used the equality from above.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I got that expansion part actually...I just dont understand how they split the equations and took part of them and just determined that the two parts of the whole equation is L, the rest isn't

Comment: @Tomy The split is chosen so that everything that is not in the expression $L(h_1,h_2)$ is $O(\|h\|)$, basically. Or, better said, you pick all things that are $O(\|h\|)$, and hope that whatever is left can be written as a linear expression.

Comment: ah .... that was hard to guess.....thanks!